# как удалить с изображения все кроме текста с помощью imageMagick

Tags: c++, imagemagick, распознавание-символов, tesseract

Пытаюсь удалить все фигуры кроме кроме текста с изображения чертежа с помощью ImageMagick (чтобы затем использовать Tesseract).[image: исходное изображение] Однако, дальше этого уйти не получается (картинка). [image: изображение чертежа после удаления горизонтальных и вертикальных линий]. Решение нужно под Windows.

P.S. На данном этапе Tesseract пока не справляется с текстом из-за лишних линий.

Comment: почти наверняка, в автоматическом режиме imageMagick такого не умеет, а в ручную — проще в любом редакторе... или просто тессеракту скормить выбранные блоки текста... если есть желание сделать всё полностью автоматически, то я бы копал в сторону opencv...

Answer (score 1):

Можно так попробовать:

```
convert shem.jpg -bordercolor black -border 2 -fuzz 90%  -fill white -floodfill +0+0 black out.jpg
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]